# Setting Enable or Disable instead of True or False using IF and ELSE statement

Tags: java, android, if-statement

So basically what I'm trying to do is that I'm sending a request using retrofit to get a data from my server and I was able to do it. My problem is that I want my program to display "Enable" or "Disable" instead of True or False and change its color based on their status ex: green for enable and red for disable. But its only displaying "Disabled" and it isn't incremented.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see your `ObjectList.getHardwareStatus()`

```
public String getHardwareStatus() {
    String HWstatus = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < hardware.length; i++) {
        Objects item = hardware[i];
        HWstatus += ((Objects) item).status + "\n\n";

    }
    return HWstatus;
}
```

It seems to returns string shows all hardwares status joined with "\n\n". Not status of specific one.

So, `response.body().getHardwareStatus().equals("true")` would be always `false`.

If you want to get first hardware's status, you could try like below.
`response.body().getHardware().get(0).statue.equals("true")`